# Return variable as well as render template

Tags: python, flask

I have written a def which will render a Flask template. However, I also want this same def to return a variable (list of dicts) to be used in my next def. How can I return both a variable as well as render a template?

So my div ends like this:

```
return render_template("portfolio.html", portfolioData = portfolioData[0], weights = weights, strategies = strategies, restrictions = restrictions, allowable_restrictions = allowable_restrictions)
```

and I also want it to return weights as a variable, so I can use it in my next dev, which starts as follows:

```
@app.route("/rebalance", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def rebalance(weights):
port_id = session["port_id"]
if request.method == "GET":
    # load security info
    securities = db.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE portfolio_id = :portfolio_id", portfolio_id = port_id)
```

Any idea how to do this? At least this is how I assume I can re-use a list of dicts made in one def into another.....

Txs!
Bart

Comment: assuming weights is independent of the logic in the function rendering the template, your can extract it to a shared function for the next view function to call.

Comment: Unassuming, you should take advantage of sessions to achieved this. A view function return one thing and one thing only, a wsgi response

Comment: Its not independent unfortunately.... So, if I understand correctly, a session is a dictionary, so can I store a list of dictionaries (which is what "weights" is) in a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some problem in the design of your application.

In Flask a view function returns only one thing - a rendered template or json or redirects to some other route etc. If you need to share some list during one request between various functions then you can use `flask.g`.

If you need to persist something between the requests then use flask session.

Comment: ...or a database.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe the flask.g thing might work. Trying to figure out how to use it. Txs!