# Using flask session to store dict

Tags: python, flask

As a follow-up on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457881/return-variable-as-well-as-render-template/44458270#44458270), I wonder how to use [`flask.g`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.g) and `flask.session` to transfer a dictionary from one function to another. If I understand `g` correctly, it only temporarily stores info until a new request. Since the function I want to transfer the dict object to, starts with a new request (it loads a new flask template), I guess I cannot use `g`. So, this leaves me to wonder whether I can use `flask.session` for this. If I try to save my dict as follows: session.dict, and then try to use this dict in a new function, it returns an "AttributeError: 'FileSystemSession' object has no attribute 'dict'.

Any idea whether the saving of a dict in a flask session is at all possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you write it to the sessions dictionary? `session['dict'] = somedict`? and later retrieve it with `session.get('dict',fallbackvalue)`. Mind that it is also possible that a user (deliberately) swaps the page requests when trying to find exploits.

Comment: Hmmm, if I do that, I get a KeyError in the next def where I try to loop through session['dict'].... :(

Comment: oh, sorry Willem, I forgot to use the "get" statement!

Comment: mind that if `get(..)` does not find the value, it will give the `fallbackvalue`. So that means that somehow, still you cannot write to the session (or the session is not persistent).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Session in flask is a dictionary. So if you need to save anything in session you can do this:

```
from flask import session
...

def foo(...):

    session['my_dict'] = my_dict


def bar(...):

    my_dict = session['my_dict']
```

Note that you need to check whether the `my_dict` is present in session before trying to use it.

Comment: Since `session` is Python's dictionary, it also has handy [methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) like `.get(key[, default_val])` and `.pop(key[, default_val])` that accept the second, optional (defaults to `None`) argument that serves as a default value. (Access via `[key]` rises `KeyError` if no such key is found.)